# Adding GroupBy rows into a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

Am doing a groupby on a datable like this:

```
List<DataRow> allRows = priceData.IndexTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();    
var fwdRowGroups = allRows.GroupBy(row => row.Field<object>("AcctId"));
DataTable fwdsDataTable = new DataTable();
```

I need to add these rows into a new datatable: fwdsDataTable.
How do I do it?Thanks.

This does not work for me:

```
foreach (var row in fwdRowGroups)
{
    fwdsDataTable.Rows.Add(row.Cast<DataRow>());                
}
```

Comment: You've got groups of rows... what are you trying to do with the groups, rather than just using `allRows`?

Comment: The intention of what you're trying to do is not quite clear. Plz explain what you need. My guessing is you're probably after filtering or sorting the records in the table then try DataView

Answer (score 0):

```
fwdsDataTable.Rows.Add(row.Cast<DataRow>());
```

The Add method adds one row, but cast returns many.  This won't quite work.  You'd have to loop through each one in the grouped result set.  Also, can you copy a row over directly?  It's been a while for me with datasets, but don't you have to create a new row for the new table and copy the data over too?

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is `for-each` and it's ok to use it here.

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
var fwdRowGroups = t.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<object>("AcctId"));

DataTable g = new DataTable();
foreach (var row in fwdRowGroups)
{
    g.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Also note the removal of excess `ToList()`. What for do you need it?

And use more specific type in `DataRow.Field<T>()`, it's created for type-safe operations. Otherwise use just `row["AcctId]`